# Open notification even application inactive or terminate

Tags: xcode, push-notification

From my apps, it can receive the notification even the apps is inactive or terminate. But,when i click on the notification to open it, it will open the main page instead of going "Journal Page" as i wish.

This will work only if the apps are active or in background. Can anyone tell me something about this problem? I have try to put the UIApplicationState for all three(Active, Inactive, Background) in didReceiveRemoteNotification method, but every notification will go through the in background state even i open the notification during the apps is active or in background.

Can anyone give me any idea to solve this problem?

This is method for remote notification:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo {

      if([userInfo valueForKey:@"app"]) { 

          NSString *action_app = [userInfo valueForKey:@"app"];
          NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
          [defaults setObject:action_app forKey:@"app"];

          NSLog(@"detect app value from UA ====> %@",action_app);

          SampleViewController *sample=[[SampleViewController alloc]init];
          [sample viewDidAppear:YES];

      }else  if([userInfo valueForKey:@"url"]){ 

          NSString *action_url = [userInfo valueForKey:@"url"];
          NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
          [defaults setObject:action_url forKey:@"url"];

          NSLog(@"detect url value from UA ====> %@",action_url);

          SampleViewController *sample=[[SampleViewController alloc]init];
          [sample viewDidAppear:YES];

      }else{

          NSLog(@"---nothing to read---");
      }

    // Send the alert to UA so that it can be handled and tracked as a direct response. This call
    // is required.
    [[UAPush shared] handleNotification:userInfo applicationState:application.applicationState];

    // Reset the badge after a push received (optional)
    [[UAPush shared] resetBadge];

    // Open inboxData when receive notification
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];

    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    self.blankviewController = [[SampleViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SampleViewController" bundle:nil];
    self.navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self.blankviewController];
    self.window.rootViewController = self.navigationController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`didReceiveRemoteNotification:` is only called if the notification is tapped when the app is in the background, or if the app is already running.

If the app is not running when the notification arrives, then when you tap on the notification the `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` method is called and the notification payload is passed to it.

Comment: then, how can i pass the notification key to go through 'didReceiveRemoteNotification' method?

Comment: @user2767343 You can't. What you can do is write a common method that will be called by both `didReceiveRemoteNotification` and `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` and will perform all the logic of handling the notification data. You can pass the notification data to it.